# Error while copying files to external hard drive

Tags: 18.04, external-hdd, copy, copy-and-paste

I am trying to copy image files to an external hard drive. The file names are like "`2020-03-25 09:21:27 624.jpg`". I have previously copied a similar data set to the same hard drive in Windows 10. However, when I try to do that in Ubuntu 18.04, the following error is displayed. I tried copying form the terminal too. What causes this error?

[image]

The following is the output of `cat /etc/fstab && cat /etc/mtab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=0807fd60-91fd-439f-abd1-ed871711cab8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=5887-5055  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /opt was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=2a5fdbe8-1614-4ac5-9d8b-bc6b3a898f9e /opt            ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=55dd57f6-7521-495f-9fde-783b70c05173 none            swap    sw              0       0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3994120k,nr_inodes=998530,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=803692k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/nvme0n1p6 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/unified cgroup2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars efivarfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/pids cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event 0 0
systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=25,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=14793 0 0
hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,relatime,pagesize=2M 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,relatime 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
configfs /sys/kernel/config configfs rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop0 /snap/gnome-logs/93 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop1 /snap/gnome-system-monitor/135 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop2 /snap/pycharm-professional/183 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop4 /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18/3 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop3 /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop5 /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/98 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop7 /snap/gtk-common-themes/1474 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop6 /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/97 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/loop9 /snap/kolourpaint/53 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop8 /snap/core/8935 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop10 /snap/kolourpaint/51 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop11 /snap/pycharm-professional/192 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop14 /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/30 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop13 /snap/gnome-system-monitor/127 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop12 /snap/youtube-dl/2778 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop15 /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18/4 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop18 /snap/core/8689 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop16 /snap/gnome-characters/399 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop17 /snap/gnome-calculator/544 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop19 /snap/youtube-dl/2638 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop20 /snap/gnome-logs/81 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop22 /snap/gnome-characters/495 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop21 /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop23 /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop24 /snap/core18/1705 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop25 /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop26 /snap/gnome-calculator/704 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop27 /snap/core18/1668 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda2 /opt ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/121 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=803692k,mode=700,uid=121,gid=125 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/1000 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=803692k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /media/rangika/My\040Book fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

Comment: Is the drive mounted? And at that exact mount point, `/media/rangika`? Use `mount` to find out.

Comment: Show your `cat /etc/fstab && cat /etc/mtab`. Edit your question.

Comment: @Gryu: Done. Thanks.

Comment: @Jos: Thank you very much. Yes, it is mounted.

Comment: I notice `root` access is specified on the `mount` line. Do you have access if you use `sudo`? e.g. `sudo touch /media/rangika/myTestFile`?

Comment: @Jos: yes. The problem I see is it takes the full filename as a directory. When I try to copy from the command prompt the following error is given: "cp: cannot create regular file '/media/rangika/MyBook/imagedownload3/2020-03-25 20:56:01 645.jpg': No such file or directory"

Comment: Are you certain there is a folder called `imagedownload3` on that drive?

Comment: BTW To be on the safe side, avoid spaces in mount points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106224/discussion-between-nilani-algiriyage-and-jos).

Answer (score 2):

Create a directory as a mountpoint without spaces as suggested in comments:

```
sudo mkdir /media/rangika/MyBook
```

Mount your drive using `/etc/fstab` record. Edit it:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/rangika/MyBook ntfs permissions,defaults 0 0
```

Then mount it using `sudo mount /media/rangika/MyBook` command.

But better, use UUID instead of `/dev/sdb1`. Use `sudo blkid | grep sdb1` command to get it. On my system it looks like:

```
$ sudo blkid | grep sdb1
/dev/sdb1: UUID="0ca03411-7a3c-4b99-b134-f53c85065339" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4e24c763-01"
```

You should set your UUID:

```
UUID=0ca03411-7a3c-4b99-b134-f53c85065339 /media/rangika/MyBook ntfs permissions,defaults 0 0
```

UUID is needed in case if you'll connect some drive to your system and your drive will get other name: not `/dev/sdb`, but `/dev/sdc`.